# i18n translations not working in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Why would i18n translations work in a `view`, but not in `AppController`?

Doesn't work - In `AppController`:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        
        debug(__('My English Text'));
        ...
    }
}
```

Works - In my `view`:

```
<p><?= __('My English Text') ?></p>
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you set the current language?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is the issue. I will analyze and revise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to set the language before calling `__()`. In my case, it was being set further down the chain in `initialize()` within `AppController`.